# White space before and after background image

Tags: html, css

There is white space appearing above and below a background image of a div (it's div class="content") even though I have margins and padding set to 0 and the background size set to "cover." Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the page:

https://sstrudel.github.io/authentic-wood/index.html

HTML: 
    `

```
<title>Authentic Wood Countertops</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="top-head">

  <div class="quote">Call 760.920.2539 for a free quote</div>

  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/rob_1098/" target="new"><img class="socmed" src="instagram.png" /></a> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/One-Source-Stone/120481204726210" target="new"><img class="socmedfb" src="facebook.png" /></a> <a href="https://twitter.com/OneSourceStone" target="new"><img class="socmed" src="twitter.png" /></ad> <a href="http://www.linkedin.com" target="new"><img class="socmed" src="linkedin.png" /></a></div>

 <div class="header">
    <img class="logo" src="Authentic_Wood_Countertops.png" />
 </div>

 <div class="navbar" id="navbar">
   <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
  <ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="design-options.html">Design Options</a></li>
   <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>

 <div class="slide-container">
  <div class="slideshow">
  <img class="mySlides" src="Countertop9.jpg">
  <img class="mySlides" src="Countertop9b.jpg">
  <img class="mySlides" src="Countertop10.jpg">
   </div>
 </div>

<div class="maincontent">
Authentic Wood Countertops has been in the business of making beautiful, high quality wood countertops since 2010. As a premier West Coast retailer of wood countertops, Authentic Wood is capable of producing custom, solid wood countertops from over 25 different species of wood in as little as 3 weeks. 
</div>

 <br /><br />
 <hr />

 <div class="content">

  <center><div class="container-2">
  <div><a href="company.html"><img src="company.jpg" width="50%"></a></div>
  <div><a href="warranty.html"><img src="warranty.jpg" width="50%"></a></div>
  <div><a href="testimonials.html"><img src="testimonials.jpg" width="50%"></a></div>
  </div></center>
 </div>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}
</script>

 <hr />

 <div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-links">
   <a href="index.html">Home</a> |
   <a href="about.html">About</a> |
   <a href="design-options.html">Design Options</a> |
   <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a> |
   <a href="#home">Blog</a> |
   <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
   </div>

    <div class="copyright-closing">
     Site design by <a href="http://samanthastreuli.com">Samantha Streuli</a> <br />
     © 2018 Authentic Wood Countertops</div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>`
```

CSS:

https://github.com/sstrudel/authentic-wood/blob/master/style.css

Comment: Hey man, I updated my answer. It's just a guess but I think I know what you are going for so I provided a better solution than the one you were asking for. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: View your page and Google Chrome > F12/Developer tools > Elements tab > "Select" one of the images.  You'll see that the "container-2" padding and margin are "0" ... but the HR above has a border-width of "1".  I suspect that's probably what you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your horizontal rules have margin on them. If you style them you can remove the spacing issue you are having.

```
hr {
   margin: 0px;
}
```

From the looks of it though I would just add a `border-top` and a `border-bottom` to your `.container-2` div as that will give you the same feel you are going for. If you go this route you will need to add padding as well. Your code could look something like this:

```
.container-2 {
   padding: 10px 0px;
   border-top: 1px solid #000;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: The hr edit did the trick! I'll try the borders out too and see what I like more. Thank you so much, you're my hero, this was driving me nuts!

Comment: @sstrudel no problem. I've definitely been there too. If this answer solved your problem please select it as the accepted answer. Thanks! :)